# Regular Expression to match single, whole words from MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, regex

I require a Regular Expression to match single words of [a-zA-Z] only with 6 or more characters.

#### The list of words:

```
a
27
it was good because
it
cat went to
four
eight is bigger
peter
pepper
objects
83
harrison99
adjetives
atom-bomb
```

#### The following would be *matched*

**pepper**

**objects**

**adjectives**

#### It isn't too bad if the following are matched too as I can strip out the duplicates after

**it was good because**

**eight is bigger**

**atom-bomb**

#### So far I have this

```
/[a-zA-z]{6,}/g
```

Which matches 6 character or more words according to [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com) but when I use it in my MySQL database to filter a table on **matches RegExp**.

1. Currently it includes words containing punctuation and other non **a-zA-Z** characters. I don't want it to include results with numbers or punctuation.
2. In an ideal world I don't want it to include a row that contains more than one word as usually the *other* words are already duplicates.

#### Actual MySQL results

If a row contains a number or punctuation and/or contain one or more words I don't want it included.

**I want only results that are single, whole words of 6+ characters**

[image: Results]

Comment: [SO] is not a code writing service; nor is it a tutorial. What problem are you having with your current code?

Comment: I have updated the question slightly to be more explicit. As the title and points 1 & 2 state, I don't want it to match rows that contain more than one word nor for it to return words that contain numbers and/or punctuation. Currently it does.

Comment: `Currently it includes words containing punctuation and other non a-zA-Z characters. I don't want it to include results with numbers or punctuation.` -- Huh, really?! Are you sure? Your regex clearly does not include punctuation or non-letters!

Comment: @Tom Lord, I know it doesn't, but it matches 'rows' that contain 6+ letter words.

Comment: You're searching anywhere in the string. As I understand you want to search for a **line** with single word longer than 6 characters. Therefore use use CR/LF as boundaries to match complete lines first `/[^\r\n]+([a-zA-z]{6,})[$\r\n]+/g` (not tested). If line with a single word may also contain white-spaces, it has to be taken into account as well.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the delimiters and add [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for start/end:

```
SELECT 'abcdef' REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{6,}$'
```

-> `1`

```
SELECT 'a abcdef' REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]{6,}$'
```

-> `0`

Also I changed `[a-zA-z]` in the character class to `[a-zA-Z]`.

---

Instead of `[a-zA-Z]` you can also use `[[:alpha:]]` [POSIX style bracket extension](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html). So it becomes:

```
^[[:alpha:]]{6,}$
```

(*As a side note*: MySql uses [Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions](http://www.arglist.com/regex/). if [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) needed, use `[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]` [See manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) for further syntax differences)